# how do I make three20 compatible with iOS 3.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I want to support version 3.1 of iOS in one of my apps which is using three20. When running the app I find few runtime errors of type "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when it is trying to invoke  methods of the iPhone SDK which doesn't exist in iOS below 3.2, some of them are:

- [UIDevice userInterfaceIdiom] which I solved looking at (https://github.com/ettore/three20/commit/7058e70d0967c6c52b5636b61c36cf8220801796)
- modalPresentationStyle on an UIViewController

So I am wondering which is the best way to make three20 compatible with version 3.1, is there any popular fork which people use for backwards compatibility?

Comment: Some of the older versions may work on 3.1, it's probably worth a look at past versions. Presumably there are reasons the latest version isn't compatibile with 3.1, so it may be an uphill struggle to get it working... I wouldn't want to attempt it myself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i maintain a iOS 3.1 compatibility branch if you want to check it out. https://github.com/kosher-penguin/three20/commits/ios-3.1-support.

You can either grab all the commits from the 24th and commit them on your local branch, or use the branch as is. (I tired implementing MGSplitViewController into thee20, which didn't end well)